# Spring Transactional With Two Data Sources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have the two database schemas and out of two, one will be used for writing and another one will be used only for reading. I have created the two data sources configuration with JPA transaction management. I have done the code like below.

**Properties:**
spring.datsource=  
spring.rodatasource=

```
**Write Config:**

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "writeEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "writeTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.pratice.app.*"})
public class WriteDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource(@Qualifier("dataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean writeEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.pratice.app.*");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager writeTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("writeEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factoryBean.getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

```
**Read Config:**

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "readEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "readTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.pratice.app.*"})
public class ReadDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.rodatasource")
    public DataSourceProperties readDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource readDatasource(@Qualifier("readDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("readDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.pratice.app.*");
        return factoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager readTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("readEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factoryBean.getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}`

**Repository:**

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

}

**Service:**

@Transactional(transactionManger = "writeTransactionManager")
public void createEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeRepository.save(employee);       
}
```

In the above method I have specified to use Write Transaction (@Transactional) but somehow it is making use of Read Transaction data not saving in to the database and getting the error saying DB is allowed only for read.

Can you please guys help me to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

If the application is able to write i do not see any reason why using two datasources for one read and another write schema. I recommend only using the write schema as it also has read access.

If you need transactions between more datasources you need to use the JTA transaction manager instead of the JPA transaction manager as it only can handle transactions with one datasource.